# How to make ST_SetZ respect NODATA?

Tags: postgis, postgis-raster

[`ST_SetZ`](https://postgis.net/docs//RT_ST_SetZ.html) looked like a very useful new function to replace this sort of thing, especially when `point` is a complex expression:

```sql
ST_SetSRID(ST_PointZ(ST_X(point), ST_Y(point), ST_Value(rast, point)), ST_SRID(point))
```

However, it appears to ignore the `NODATA` value of the raster, and return it raw instead of using `NULL`:

```sql
SELECT
  ST_Summary(rast),
  ST_Value(rast, point),
  ST_Z(ST_SetZ(rast, point))
FROM ...
```

```
ST_Summary   | Raster of 100x100 pixels has 1 band and extent of BOX(338800 573100,338900 573200)
             |     band 1 of pixtype 32BF is in-db with NODATA value of -3.4028234663852886e+38
ST_Value     | <null>
ST_Z         | -340282346638528860000000000000000000000
```

Is there any way to get that to work properly, or is it simply a bug that will need a fix?

---

I'm using `postgis-3.2.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1`:

> POSTGIS="3.2.0 c3e3cc0" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="140" GEOS="3.10.2-CAPI-1.16.0" PROJ="8.2.1" GDAL="GDAL 3.4.1, released 2021/12/27" LIBXML="2.9.12" LIBJSON="0.15" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3" WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)" RASTER

Comment: There's no [tag:postgis-3.2] tag and I don't have enough rep to create it.

Comment: Maybe "where ST_Value(rast, point)) is not null".

Comment: @user30184 no, I want it to return a point with Z set to null/NaN, not to return nothing.

Comment: Hotfix: `NULLIF(ST_Z(ST_SetZ(rast, point)), ST_BandNoDataValue(rast, <band>))`

Comment: @geozelot that also doesn't return a point with Z set to null/NaN

Comment: @OrangeDog your respective query does not attempt to return a point. In the first case you can simply add the same logic to the `Z` ordinate. To your actual question: that is probably not implemented as you usually do not want NULLs in GEOMETRY coordinates.

Comment: @geozelot `ST_SetZ` returns a point. If I didn't want a point I would just use `ST_Value`. The example query uses `ST_Z` so you can see what the value is. You do want NULLs in your Z/M coordinates if the data is missing for that point.

Comment: @OrangeDog what I am trying to say here is having `NULL` *inside* the `GEOMETRY` type (except maybe the `M` ordinate) leads to all sorts of undefined behavior downtream. Depending on the PostGIS version between zero and a handful of operations fail silently (returning `NULL` or invalid geometries), while most simply error out. I assume returning a value is a dev decision to keep integrity intact.

Comment: @geozelot the trouble is that you end up with nonsensical contours with no way to recover the discontinuities once any further steps are taken. It's working fine for me right now using the first example in the question, but it's very verbose.